# How many times can a Fighter hit while using Two Weapon Fighting, Extra Attack and Action Surge on the same turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, fighter

I've come to multiple conclusions while reading how these three mechanics work in conjunction with one another. I see ways to argue that one might be able to attack up to 6 different times in one turn. For instance, I use my attack action to use my LH weapon ( atk twice from Extra Attack ) Then Bonus Action for my RH, again attacking twice. Then finally Action surge to attack a third time,( but still getting to do it twice from Extra Attack ).

Is this the correct logic? Is there some other order of operations which makes the outcome different, or does Extra Attack not apply in some cases?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Related] [Do these different numbers of attack stack within one round?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55968)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How many attacks can a Dual Wielder make at 5th level?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/55589)

Comment: Agree with the Duplicate's and related comments. This question, as written, has been answered by other questions on this forum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A dual wielding fighter, using extra attack and action surge gets **5 attacks**.

Here's their action order:

- Action 1: Attack 1. Attack 2.
- Bonus Action: Attack 3.
- Action 2 (Action Surge): Attack 4. Attack 5.

They do not get a second bonus action to use, and as such cannot take the other hand attack again, that only happens once per turn.

Also, the bonus action attack is *not* an attack action, and as such, does not benefit from extra attack.